# Check origin of correlation between categorical variables

Tags: r, correlation, chi-squared, pearson

I have two variables, *status* (tells if the patient is new, recidivist...) and *result*. There are 5 types of *status* and 10 types of *results*. I already did the Chi-squared test and Cramer's V test and the two variables are dependent.

However, I want to know how the type of *status* interfeers on the type *result* (for example, if new patients are more likely to be cured, if transfered patients are less likely do die, and so on).

I was using Pearson residuals and plotting it but I've read that it's not recommended. Do you guys have any idea? I couldn't find any answer.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This may help https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00220973.1995.9943797  Full text is available at researchgate

Comment: @Mohanasundaram thank you man!